# Criar diretiva para background-image

Tags: angular, ionic3

Eu possuo uma diretiva para imagens, onde caso uma imagem não carregue eu exibo uma imagem padrão.

**Diretiva:**

```
import { Directive, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'img[default]',
  host: {
    '(error)':'updateUrl()',
    '(load)': 'load()',
    '[src]':'src'
   }
})
export class ImagePreloadDirective {
  @Input() src:string;
  @Input() default:string;
  @HostBinding('class') className

  updateUrl() {
    this.src = this.default;
    this.className = 'image-default';
  }
  load(){
    //this.className = 'image-default';
  }
}
```

**Uso:**

```
<img 
    [src]="'assets/imgs/img-name.png"
    default="assets/imgs/image-default.png">
```

Porém, gostaria de fazer o mesmo para uma outra situação em que uso `background-image`.

```
<figure [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(assets/imgs/teste_344x120-.jpg)'}"></figure>
```

Entretanto, não estou conseguindo alterar ou adaptar a diretiva que eu já tenho para funcionar quando o `background-image` não carregar.

Answer (score -1):

Cara, eu no momento utilizo este código para colocar um background de fundo em uma página... como em sua situação, se eu não encontrar o que eu quero eu uso um default :

```
  getMyStyles() {
    const myStyles = {
      'background-image': !this.imgBackground
        ? 'url(\'/assets/images/background/1.png\')'
        : 'url(' + this.imgBackground + ')'
    };
    return myStyles;
  }
```

E no html você usaria esta função :

```
<div [ngStyle]="getMyStyles()">
```

funciona perfeitamente aqui.

Comment: Olá @duardbr, obrigado pela resposta. Mas a verificação que vocês esta fazendo é se a variável imgBackground possui valor. No meu caso, o que a diretiva acima faz é verificar se a url da imagem é válida. Por exemplo, mesmo que a exista um valor de URL pode ser que a imagem não exista no servidor por algum motivo. Neste caso, é retornado 'not found 404' e a imagem não é exibida. A diretiva acima corrige esse problema para elementos img, porém estou buscando uma forma de fazer o mesmo quando a imagem é usada como 'background-image'.